# How to create mysql trigger that inserts row into history table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table of questions.

My goal is to create a state of questions, so I can retrieve them at date T even if they were modified.

So what I want to acheieve is to create a trigger that runs on update, delete, insert and that duplicates the (deleted, updated, inserted) row from question into question_history

1) can I create 1 trigger for these 3 events or must I create 3 triggers ?

2) can I insert a WHOLE row or must I insert field by field ?

Any clue ?

regards

Comment: Go for trigger writing.

Comment: There u go. Was hard to find, I admit. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: - ok, but is that possibel to create 1 single trigger for these 3 events or must I create 1 trigger per event ?

- what sql to retrieve a whole ROW or should I make an insert field by field ?

Comment: as far as i am getting your question i thing you have 2 tables question and question_history,
and you want to maintain question_history table whenever there is update, delete or insert in question table,,,right .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) can I create 1 trigger for these 3 events or must I create 3
>   triggers ?

3 triggers

> 2) can I insert a WHOLE row or must I insert field by field ?

field by field